# Unity Crashes :: Top and Side bars missing

Tags: 14.04, unity

While I was working on Firefox, I faced black busy screen and I had to shutdown my firefox to make my computer responsive again. When I restarted firefox, it couldn't start. So I restarted whole computer. After login, side and top bar was missing. I have no clue what is wrong!

Within few hour, we have noticed this problem to many computers in network. Can anyone help or what can be the cause?

This issue is not happening only while working with firefox but chrome and thunderbird. This issue happened on Ubuntu 14.04.1 and 14.04.2.

We have tried everything, reinstalling unity, reseting user configuration without luck. When I login as a guest, it works but on few computers and not all.

Comment: Have you tried resetting Unity?

Comment: Yes we did without luck

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to try first is to reset Unity and compiz.

 Enter enter the terminal the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Followed by:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```